# Embed PayPal in an IFRAME

Tags: html, iframe, paypal

Is it possible to embed paypal in an IFRAME. I have tried to do this but it just came back a blank page as if there was nothing on it. I dont want to use adaptive payments. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I am using PayPal Payments Advanced and currently working with support to enable it within an Iframe. Support has repeatedly said that it is possible and the layout C exists for that purpose, although I have not been able to get it to work due to X-FRAME-OPTIONS. Even if they do support it and I did find a way to get it to work, my understanding is that it will be susceptible to the click-jacking vulnerability.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are <strike>probably</strike> prohibiting it by setting the [`X-FRAME-OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header. It's a security measure and there is no way to work around it.

If you have a payment running through PayPal, you can provide a "back to site" link - that's all you can do.

Answer (score 10):

You can host PayPal in an iframe only with Adaptive Payments for Digital Goods / Express Checkout for Digital Goods (kind of), Hosted Solution (hosted Website Payments Pro, not currently available in the US), Payflow Pro, and Payflow Link.

You cannot host Website Payments Standard checkout pages in iframes. As Pekka stated, PayPal does set the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header.

Comment: +1. Adaptive Payments doesn't allow itself to be embedded either; same story as with Express Checkout; Digital Goods only (sort of).

Comment: I want to use parallel payments with adaptive payments.  The payments are for a service.  Can the entire workflow, from login to payment, be embedded in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

No way to get around the same origin policy.

A way around this is to create an anchor tag in the iframe:

```
<a href="<?=$paypal_redirect?>" target="_blank">Continue Checking out</a>
or
<a href="<?=$paypal_redirect?>" target="_top">Continue Checking out</a>
```

The above will only allow the continuation of the checkout process in another tab/window; it will not process the checkout within your iframe.