# How to Form POST to Paypal from WinJS iframe Windows 8 App?

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8, paypal, winjs

I have a Windows 8 App using Javascript/HTML and within an iframe I have a Paypal form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Pages">
<select name="os0">
    <option value="10">$1.95</option>
    <option value="25">$2.95</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="[removed]">
<input type="image" src="/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
</form>
```

This form works perfectly fine in all browsers, including IE10 but when submitted from within the iframe in the Windows 8 App, it will lead the user to the Paypal homepage.  This usually indicates an issue with the form.  I have tried hosted Paypal buttons, encrypted, un-encrypted buttons and they all exhibit the same behavior.  Only when I submit this form from within the Windows 8 App does it go to the Paypal.com homepage.

I have also tried adding every URL to my manifest as allowed URLs:

```
<ApplicationContentUriRules>
<Rule Match="http://example.com" Type="include" />
<Rule Match="http://*.example.com" Type="include" />
<Rule Match="http://paypal.com" Type="include" />
<Rule Match="http://*.paypal.com" Type="include" />
<Rule Match="https://paypal.com" Type="include" />
<Rule Match="https://*.paypal.com" Type="include" />
</ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

I tried adding/removing the sandbox attribute and adding all combinations of the properties like so:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-scripts allow-popups" src="http://example.com/paypalbtn.html"></iframe>
```

If I remove the `target="_blank"` then the Windows 8 App will navigate to a black screen and hang.  I am forced to alt-tab and shutdown the app.  I assume it's a problem with the form POST to a new window in another process.

How can I launch Paypal from within the iframe of a Windows 8 App?

Is a form POST required?  I am now realizing that a form GET works.

Comment: i think that payapal dose not support iframe form submit

Comment: @SVarun is correct. This issue is covered by [this thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464173/embed-paypal-in-an-iframe).  It's a security measure, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal will block the form POST to the new window when launched from an iframe in the Windows 8 App.  The result is you see the Paypal homepage instead of the purchase order form.

I can confirm that simply switching the form method to `GET` and using a `target="_blank"` works perfectly without issue:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="get" target="_blank">
```

Another way around this issue within the iframe is to use a standard anchor tag around text or an image and manually create the URL like so:

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?custom=[custom info]&item_name=[URL encoded name]&item_number=[num]&amount=9.95&currency_code=USD&cmd=_xclick&business=[paypal email address]&return=[URL encoded URL]">Buy Now</a>
```

The credit for this answer goes to this page about [Paypal links instead of buttons](http://forums.asp.net/t/1037392.aspx/1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think paypal allows iframe support. They most likely use this:

[X-Frame Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

It allows them to detect if the page is rendered in a iframe and if so prevent it loading..(aka show blank page) like you are experiencing.

And there is no way around this.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that Paypal sends a response header of `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN`.  That will stop Paypal.com from being rendered in my iframe but I am trying to execute a form post to a new window from the iframe.  That URL in the iframe is my URL so example.com is posting to paypal.com in a new window.  The post seems valid but I presume Paypal is detecting something funny and showing the paypal homepage.

Comment: From what it says `The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.` it means the new window is no longer the same origin - or at least thats how I am understanding it.

Comment: That's okay since Paypal isn't being displayed in the iframe.  I think I should be able to post to a new window which is in a different origin.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with PayPal and a Windows Store app. I just posted my solution to the problem in this thread:

[Windows Store HTML app with popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283092/windows-store-html-app-with-popup-window/)