# Number of in-app purchases for Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Windows Store app for a newspaper in the Windows Store. Each issue (one per work day) can be bought using in-app purchases. In Windows Store, it looks like i can define only 100 in app purchases. In my case, that is about 4 months of daily issues.

Is 100 really the limit? Has anyone found a way to add more?

I cannot find a way to add more in-app purchases to the app. The milit of 100 would be a really stupid constraint and I would need to remove to ability to buy old issues in order to add new issues.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 doesn't support subscription-based purchases but it does support time-limited purchases.

One option is to let the user purchase "credits" that can be applied toward an issue. Similar to how Audible lets you purchase audiobooks with credits.

Here's the thing though. Newspapers make money off advertisements. The purchase price isn't for the content, it's for the materials that it costs to deliver the paper. A digital paper costs nothing to deliver so why are you charging for it?

Comment: The business model is decided by the customer. They have an iOS app that works that way without any problems. It is not a tabloid living from ads, they are a serious newspaper and the customer pay for the content.

Comment: You downvoted for my followup question? Because I did answer your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The store does not support subscriptions. However you can just use a third party provider for this. 
As mentioned in the 'Flexible business Model'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh852650.aspx

> The Windows Store provides you with the freedom to choose the business
>   model that’s right for your apps. The Store provides full platform
>   support for free apps, trials (both time-based and feature-based), and
>   paid apps, as well as in-app purchases. You’re free to manage customer
>   transactions directly using your own or third-party services for
>   in-app purchases and subscriptions, or use the services provided by
>   the Windows Store. For apps that are supported by ads, you’re free to
>   choose the ad platform that best meets your goals.

Paypal is accessible via this api:
http://paypal.github.com/Windows8SDK/

or directly via a form post

[How to Form POST to Paypal from WinJS iframe Windows 8 App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999622/how-to-form-post-to-paypal-from-winjs-iframe-windows-8-app)

Comment: There is a problem with such solutions. I dpo not knwo the identity of the user (API does not offer it) so the purchases would not be tranferable between different devices of the user.

Comment: You could use Roaming storage to store data about which issues were purchased. Might want to provide some kind of encryption/validation as well to avoid users circumventing it.

Comment: You know they've successfully purchased or not, and you can link that info to the current live id which you can require the user be signed in with (or other oAuth solution)