# Windows Store HTML app with popup window

Tags: javascript, windows, paypal, webview

I'm wrapping a web app in a Windows Store app shell using a `x-ms-webview`. This works fine, but I have one problem. I use PayPal and since PayPal doesn't allow to be `iframed` I need to open PayPal in a new browser window.

On regular browsers this isn't a problem. The window open and when the user returns from PayPal I can a callback on "`opener`" and update the users account.

But when doing this in a Windows Store app the `window.open` triggers IE to launch. The problem is to return to my app and let it know that the user finished the transaction.

My first idea was just to use a `URI activation`. This kind of works, but I having trouble knowing if the PayPal page was launch from a regular browser or an app. I also think it is confusing for the user to be taken to another app to make the purchase.

I would prefer to have the window open in my app, but I'm not sure how I would open open a new `x-ms-webview` as a modal window overlapping existing webview.

What is the best way to communicate from the current web view and the app? 
Can I use `postMessage` to send messages between the app and the `x-ms-webview` even though the src of the web view is a http hosted site?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get around this problem. I am looking at a similar issue. We have wrapped our site in a windows app using webview and the site supports authentication using Google,Facebook,etc. These services popup a window on the normal browser. But in the app, they launch the IE and hence loose the authenticated session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

First, you will need to use a https url for the embedded site. The reason for this is that the solution include `postMessage` and `invokeScriptAsync`.

First, my markup in my app looks something like this to have one webview for the app and one web view for the PayPal popup.

```
<x-ms-webview id="webview" src="https://myapp"></x-ms-webview>

<div id="paypalContainer">
    <div class="paypal-header"><button id="paypalClose" type="reset">Close</button></div>
    <div class="paypal-body"><x-ms-webview id="paypalWebView" src="about:blank"></x-ms-webview></div>
</div>
```

Then, when the web app is ready to use PayPal, I use window.external.notify to send a message to the Windows Store app.

```
if (window.external && 'notify' in window.external) {
    window.external.notify(JSON.stringify({ action: 'paypal' }));
}
```

The windows store app listens for Script Notify events and displays the paypalWebView.

```
webview.addEventListener("MSWebViewScriptNotify", scriptNotify);

    function scriptNotify(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.value);
        if (data.action === "paypal") {
            var loading = document.getElementById("loading-indicator");
            var container = document.getElementById("paypalContainer");
            var paypalWebView = document.getElementById("paypalWebView");
            var paypalClose = document.getElementById("paypalClose");
            if (paypalWebView.src === "about:blank") {
                paypalWebView.addEventListener('MSWebViewNavigationCompleted', function (e) {
                    loading.classList.remove('loading');

                    var successUrl = '/paypal/success';
                    if (event.target.src.indexOf(successUrl) !== -1) {
                        var operation = webview.invokeScriptAsync("updateUser");
                        operation.oncomplete = function () {
                            (new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Your account is refreshed", "")).showAsync().done();
                        };
                        operation.start();
                    }
                });

                paypalWebView.addEventListener('MSWebViewNavigationStarting', function (e) {
                    console.log("Started loading");
                    loading.classList.add('loading');
                });

                paypalClose.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    container.classList.remove("visible");
                });
            }

            paypalWebView.src = "https://myapp/paypal/";
            container.classList.add("visible");
        }
    }
```

So, basically, when the script notify event fires, I parse the sent json string to an object and check what kind of action it is. If it's the first time I run this I setup some naviation event handlers that check if the web view reach the Success page. If we have, I use incokeScriptAsync to let the web app know that we're done so it can refresh the user account the new payment.

I think you can use a similar solution for authentication and just check your your return URL after authenticating.

Hope this helps!