# PayPal Donation Confirmation on my web-page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, curl, paypal

there is a donate form on my web-site. After clicking on donate button(form submit) it redirects to the external PayPal payment confirmation page. Is it possible, to embed(not with iframe or popup) this confirmation into my web-site? I don't want my customers to be redirected. For ex, after clicking on submit button, person is to be redirected to another page **ON MY WEB SITE**, where he can approve his payment.
Thanks for any response!

Comment: I don' think this is possible, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal uses `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`, so this prevents its from being used in an iframe. Its simply for security, and you can't work around. All it means is that the page, has to be on Paypal, or else Paypal won't be *as* secure. You can provide a back-link after you complete the transaction, but that's basically all you can do. Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Paypal limits iFrame usage, for security reasons, with the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header.

Sign up for a business or higher level account at PayPal or use an e-commerce plugin in WordPress to keep your customers on your site as they checkout. This is the most common solution to keeping PayPal users on your site.

Dupe: [Embed PayPal in an IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464173/embed-paypal-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Do you know any WP plugin for donation, that keeps people on site without redirection to paypal?